# Bluemix availability monitoring - Scripting support

Tags: ibm-cloud, availability-monitoring

Bluemix availability monitoring provides scripting support for Selenium only. Is there a way, I can have my shell or bash script that does following
- Builds a url
- Calls url using curl
- Process the response

My current urls are protected by Bluemix IAM. To call url, I need to pass access token in the header. The access token expires every hour which makes it impossible to use Bluemix availability monitoring service.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is only selenium script support.

There are plans for javascript (not shell) for REST APIs, but there are no firm dates when that might be available.

IAM tokens that expire every hour will make it difficult to monitor regardless of choice of monitoring mechanism.  I am not familiar enough with IAM to provide much advice.  Perhaps a second process outside the monitoring can refresh the accessToken?

Some who use Bluemix Availability Monitoring use APIConnect.  Perhaps those tokens are less ephemeral, but I'm not sure how to map APIConnect access to IAM.